# AngularJS https get response but, didn't display

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I implemented a backend to provide data to front end based on Spring boot. It works fine. When I use chrome to browse the localhost, it works 
URL: http://localhost:4983/employee/ALL/

Response:

```
'[{"id":1,"name":"ALFRED","dept":"871m","email":"woodspring.toronto@gmail.com","salary":120000},
{"id":2,"name":"FRANK","dept":"TCTO","email":"tzuchi.toronto@gmail.com","salary":920000},
{"id":3,"name":"NANCY","dept":"TDSB","email":"nancy.tseng@gmail.com","salary":620000},
{"id":4,"name":"TONG","dept":"NYGH","email":"tony.tang@gmail.com","salary":720000},
{"id":5,"name":"CINDY","dept":"University Of Victoria","email":"cindy.huang@uvic.edu","salary":9987654},
{"id":6,"name":"CINDY HUANG","dept":"University Of Victoria","email":"cindy.huang@uvic.edu","salary":9987654}]'
```

But, when I use HTML and Angular JS to $http, the data didn't show as expected.

Here is my Angular JS code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular JS Includes</title>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid grey;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        table tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        table tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function employeeController($scope, $http) {
           $http({method: 'GET',  url: 'http://localhost:4983/employee/ALL/'} )
  .success(function (response) {
         $scope.employees =  response;
console.log( $scope.employees);
$scope.context = "IT works";
  });
        }
    </script>

    <h2>AngularJS Employee Application</h2>
    <div ng-app=""  ng-controller="employeeController">
{{  context  }}
{{ employees[0].id }} 
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Employee ID</th>
                <th>Employee Name</th>
                <th>Employee Dept</th>
                <th>employee Email</th>
  <th>employee Salary</th>
  <th>{{ msg  }}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="empl in employees">
                <td>{{  empl.id  }}</td>
                <td>{{  empl.name }}</td>
             <td>{{  empl.dept  }}</td>
                <td>{{  empl.email }}</td>
             <td>{{  empl.salary  }}</td>
  <td>{{  msg  }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
{{ msg }}

<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I browse this page on Chrome, I can see the backend spring-boot has been called and responds with data. But, the front end doesn't display it. Can anyone see what I did wrong?

Comment: where you defined module??

Comment: did you check the browser console for any errors ? or the value of the log ?

Answer (score 0):

From [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http](http://http%20docs)
The response object has these properties:

data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

In this case use: **$scope.employees =  response.data;**

Answer (score 0):

For starters, referring to $http service docs:

> The $http legacy promise methods `success` and `error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `then` method instead.

Try changing your code to

```
function employeeController($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',  
    url: 'http://localhost:4983/employee/ALL/'
  }).then(function (response) {
      $scope.employees =  response;
      console.log($scope.employees); //check what this outputs
      $scope.context = "IT works";
    });
}
```

Also surely you realise, giving us the localhost URL is not going to be of any use here.

Additionally there could be many things wrong with the code, it could be much better if you could check your browser console for any errors or atleast check the console for the output of `console.log($scope.employees)`.